# Probability of an element belonging to a certain bin in the histogram

Tags: matlab, statistics, histogram

If I have a vector (of length 8000 samples) and I created its histogram for 68 bins using the commands (Matlab)

```
Nbin = ceil(exp(0.626 + 0.4*log(length(psi)- 1)));%// Compute probability
h = hist(psi,Nbin);
```

I wan't to know, for every sample of my input vector, what is the probability of it existing in every bin. How do I get that?

I will be using that to calculate the Shannon Entropy of my data.
Thanks

Comment: `h` is he number of elements in each bin, so divide it by the vector length to get the probability

Comment: I'm confused by your statement about "the probability of a sample from the input vector existing in a bin" -- it is 1 for the bin which the sample belongs to, 0 for all others. Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: @Adriel This gives the unconditional probability of any (new) sample belonging to a bin y. If I understand the OP correctly, he wants the probability of a sample belonging to a bin y given the condition that it has value x which is a bit more complicated.

Comment: Yes mikkola, that is what I thought all along, but the paper explaining how shanon Entropy is calculated says that. Here is a link to the paper maybe I'm missing something: https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Frank_Boers/publication/238504043_Synchronization_Tomography_Anatomical_Localization_of_Synchronized_Brain_Rhythms_with_Magnetoencephalography/links/0c9605278a4c9843a6000000/Synchronization-Tomography-Anatomical-Localization-of-Synchronized-Brain-Rhythms-with-Magnetoencephalography.pdf (pg 5 synchronization) There are other papers but they are in the database I can't share them freely.

Comment: As @Adiel recommended you should divide  `h` by length of the data but here you should compute histograms of sliding windows and divide them by the length of  window.